# Term for doing something little by little?

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a single word that means doing something but not totally finishing whatever it is. Like if one is studying for an exam, that person won't review everything, he/she will just review certain parts of a lecture for the time being.

Edit: I don't mean it like it is a bad thing. What I'm trying to say on the example is to review for an exam little by little on multiple times.

Comment: Question and question description ask for different things. Cherry picking which parts you want and ignoring the rest is different from studying little by little. One could do one or the other, or both, or neither. They are different ideas. Which do you want an answer for?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The review for the exam was 'piecemeal' (*adv.* and *adj.*):

> 1. By a *small amount at a time*; in stages: articles acquired piecemeal.

[piecemeal. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved January 20 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/piecemeal . Emphasis mine.]

For example,

> Her review for the exam was **piecemeal**.

'Piecemeal' communicates the chronological dimension of what I understand to be the meaning you want.

Comment: *+1*  Good one...

Comment: I don't know how widespread this is, but at least for me piecemeal has a connotation of the pieces never quite managing to cover the whole. This implication could be one to keep in mind when deciding whether to use this word.

Comment: It also has a connotation (for me) of the pieces being done in "random order", as opposed to in some specific order.  If it were done in a defined order, I would use a different term, such as "incrementally"

Answer (score 50):

***Incrementally***

Incremental, according to [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incremental):

> of, relating to, being, or occurring in especially small increments
>   [e.g.] incremental additions

[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/incremental) says:

> If you are making incremental progress in math, you are moving slowly
>   but steadily forward. Incremental describes regular, measurable
>   movements that are usually small

**Incrementally** is doing things by increments.  In your case you are reviewing your course-work incrementally, in easy to absorb bite-size portions.

Doing this for a week is better in the long run than cramming for hours the night before an exam; you will retain more.

Comment: Usually used in conjunction with _improvement_: incremental improvement.  Note that increments are typically fixed-size chunks.  Someone who sets aside an hour a night to study might be described as learning the material incrementally.

Answer (score 13):

***Gradually***

According to [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gradual) gradual is defined as (for this meaning):

> 1:  proceeding by steps or degrees
>      2:  moving, changing, or developing by fine or often imperceptible degrees

[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/gradual) (for this meaning) words it a bit differently:

> proceeding in small stages

**Gradually** is often used to describe things that are done over time, in relatively small amounts each time.

Comment: One would not say one is gradually studying (unless one was trying to be funny); one would say one is _gradually zeroing in on an answer_ to a problem, or maybe _gradually getting better at playing the piano_.  It usually means a lot of time is required.  (As the above definitions explain: taking small steps means the process takes a long time.)  It does _not_ imply not finishing (as in the original question).  It implies the process is ongoing.

Comment: Your comment applies to every answer here. Studying was probably not a great example since unless one is *cramming* one does not study everything all at once. Similarly for "not finishing" -- also, one could interpret the question as *not finished **yet***, not just *will not finish*; **Gradually** *does* apply to *not finished yet*. One would not say one is studying *piecemeal* or studying *incrementally* either, because it is implied. It's a matter of perspective and context.

Answer (score 4):

[**Pace**](https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=korean+to+english&oq=korean+to+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0j69i57j0l3.1551j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=pace+define)

Google Definition:

> Verb
>
> do something at a slow and steady rate or speed in order to avoid overexerting oneself.

Rather than cramming for an exam, a student should pace her studies throughout the semester.

**Update in response to downvote**.

While the definition of the word does not exactly fit the OP's word "little by little," I feel this word is very commonly used in the above situation by students:

> Hey, what are you trying to do? Memorize the entire book in the first week of class? Pace yourself!
>
> (while cramming) I'm not going to put myself through this again. I'm going to pace myself next semester.

Answer (score 3):

***[Iteratively](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iteratively)***

> b :  relating to or being iteration of an operation or procedure

So then, what's [iteration](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iteration)?

> 1
>   :  the action or a process of iterating or repeating: as
>   a :  a procedure in which repetition of a sequence of operations yields results successively closer to a desired result

Answer (score 2):

**Intermittently**.  Do a little now, then a little more later, then some more tomorrow... as time permits.  You're doing it with interruptions, not all at once.  Also it's not predictable how much time you can spend each session; the durations are random.  (Contrast with the above *incrementally*.)

Comment: I disagree with this one - something can happen intermittently without in any way advancing a long term goal.  My car's windshield wipers, for example.  They operate once every set interval, but they never get any closer to a "done" state.

Comment: Consider "I could only work on the project intermittently, but it was eventually completed." That doesn't really tell me that you took baby steps to get the project done, it just tells me the work you did wasn't at regular intervals. Each time you worked on it, you could have made a lot of progress, and it still could have been intermittent work. Can you provide an example with this word that does communicate the idea that work was completed in small portions?

Answer (score 2):

[Inchmeal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inchmeal):

> Little-by-little, gradually: '*the troops moved through the village inchmeal, recapturing it virtually house by house*'.

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Hi, Kathys, We encourage users to include a link/reference/research that can support an answer. I edited your post and please take a look.  Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

little by little [ lit-l ]
Main Entry: gradually

Part of Speech: adverb

Definition: happening slowly, evenly

Synonyms: bit by bit, by degrees, by installments, constantly, continuously, deliberately, gently, imperceptibly, in small doses, inch by inch, increasingly, little by little, moderately, perceptibly, piece by piece, piecemeal, progressively, regularly, sequentially, serially, steadily, step by step, successively, unhurriedly

Antonyms: abruptly, fastly, intermittently, suddenly

Comment: The OP tagged the question "single-word-requests"...maybe you should hyphenate "little-by-little"? I realize it's a formality, but that's kind'a the point. Also, on EL&U, material copied from a source is (a) supplemented with reasoning for choosing that response; (b) attributed scrupulously to the source. FYI.

Comment: In an odd twist, "Gradually" seems not to be an answer yet given.

Answer (score 1):

There is also *successive*.

> following one after the other in a series : following each other without interruption

From [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/successive).

But I'm not a native speaker so I don't know for sure.

Comment: Successive would imply doing different parts of the overall task on separate occasions.  The question refers to repeating sections of the work, which is not the same.

Comment: The point with _successive_ is there is a dependency: you can't do this part before you've completed the previous one.  It doesn't say anything about the element of time, which the OP was concerned with.  It also doesn't really talk about progress (finishing or not); it's about how the process is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Cherry-pick**

Definition:

> Selectively choose (the most beneficial or profitable items, opportunities, etc.) from what is available

Use in a sentence:

> The company should buy the whole airline and not just cherry-pick its best assets

Source: [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20cherry%20picking&oq=define%20cherrypi&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4976j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Stepwise (or step-wise). In the tech world, the term "stepwise refinement" is, or was, used for moving ahead in a project bit by bit. Also "Iterative" is bandied about, with one cycle of work being called an iteration.